# Python Web Scraping - POST & GET

Tags: python, parsing, post, get, web-scraping

I am attempting to collect public real estate data from the following website: http://icare.fairfaxcounty.gov/search/commonsearch.aspx?mode=address.  I have solved the first part, which uses a POST request to search for a given street (Main St in this example).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib, urllib2

streetName = 'main'
suffix = 'st'

url = "http://icare.fairfaxcounty.gov/search/CommonSearch.aspx?mode=ADDRESS"

values = {  '__VIEWSTATE':'/wEPDwUJLTgxMDY5OTM2DxQrAAJkZxYCZg9kFgQCBQ8PFgIeB1Zpc2libGVoZBYCZg9kFgJmD2QWAgIBD2QWAgIBD2QWAgIBDxBkZBYAZAIHDw8WAh8AaGRkZA==',
      '__EVENTVALIDATION' :'/wEWCAL/k9GbBALq6fr+DwKw9e7KCwKNs9bAAwLYyu+sAwLE8frfBwK5mc2yBwLunJLZAQ==',
      'PageNum':'',
      'SortBy':'PARID',
      'SortDir': 'asc',
      'PageSize':50,
      'hdAction':'Search',
      'hdIndex': '',
      'sIndex':-1,
      'hdListType':'PA',
      'hdJur': '', 
      'inpNumber': '',
      'inpUnit': '',
      'inpStreet':streetName ,
      'inpSuffix1':suffix,
      'selSortBy':'PARID' ,
      'selSortDir': 'asc' ,
      'selPageSize':50 ,
      'searchOptions$hdBeta': '',
      'btSearch':'SEARCH',
      'mode':'ADDRESS',
      'mask': ''}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
pageText = response.read()

#now I can parse the list of addresses from this page
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageText)
```

However, I cannot figure out how to create the effect of clicking on one of those addresses, so that I can parse that information.  Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

there is no `effect of clicking`, its just http get and post requests.

one direction is to write [a scrapy spider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) that will include the following steps:

1. on its first `parse` function use a [FormRequest](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html) to get the addresses lines
2. use [scrapy xpath selector](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html) to loop on them and create further requests
3. define and use the items you want to scrape and the format you'd like to get the result in

It has some learning curve, but I'm pretty sure its the right direction, at least one of such, good luck!